# PostgreSql/SQLalchemy creating tables with columns that are the wrong datatype

Tags: python, sql, postgresql, sqlalchemy

When I run the following query to create a table in PostgreSQL:

```
CREATE TABLE mytable(
  siteid NUMERIC,
  y NUMERIC,
  n NUMERIC,
  flags TEXT [],
  notes VARCHAR (300)
  );
```

The query creates a table where the datatype for the siteid column is TEXT, not NUMERIC like what was specified in the query.

Is there a syntax error somewhere that I am missing?

I'm running the query inside a python script with SQLalchemy.

Comment: A guess: the table has been created before with the wrong type.

Comment: If the old table had been deleted, would the type persist though?

Comment: As it is right now, the issue you are describing cannot be reproduced. I suggest you include the steps to reproduce that issue and how you discovered `siteid` was created as text instead of numeric.